Nginx - Securing HTTP Traffic to Upstream Servers
I read the article 'Securing HTTP Traffic to Upstream Servers' at this link: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/.
If the proxied server is a HTTPS server, the connection between NGINX and the proxied server will be HTTPS. Why is there a need to set up proxy_ssl_certificate and proxy_ssl_certificate_key in NGINX?
